# Browser Caching with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, browser

I have a quite long slideshow of images, all rendered via the awesome Paperclip. 
Those images won't change very often, so I'd like to make use of browser caching. 
Problem is Paperclip appends a unique load id to the image url. 
(eg: pancakes.png?1275839986)

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When specifying the image url using:

```
UrModel.image.url(:style)
# results in: /system/model/000/001/style/style.png?<atimestamp>
```

Pass in a second parameter which indicates whether or not to include the timestamp:

```
UrModel.image.url(:style, false)
# results in: /system/model/000/001/style/style.png
```

Read more about paperclips caching helper: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Tips

Answer (score 0):

That numeric suffix is stored in the database itself by paperclip and is *not* unique per page load. It's there for caching reasons, actually.